# Tamosta watering timer

Tags: timer, mqtt, tasmota

I'm trying to make a watering timer that turns on for 20 minutes and off for 30 and repeat the cycle during daytime. Also, change the cycle to 20 minutes ON at night-time and 1hour OFF.

I'm using these timers as a base, but I'm missing some rules to complete it.

Timer1

```
{"Enable":1,"Mode":1,"Time":"00:00","Window":0,"Days":"1111111","Repeat":1,"Output":1,"Action":1}
```

Timer2

```
{"Enable":1,"Mode":1,"Time":"00:20","Window":0,"Days":"1111111","Repeat":1,"Output":1,"Action":0}
```

Timer3

```
{"Enable":1,"Mode":2,"Time":"00:00","Window":0,"Days":"1111111","Repeat":1,"Output":1,"Action":1}
```

Timer4

```
{"Enable":1,"Mode":2,"Time":"00:20","Window":0,"Days":"1111111","Repeat":1,"Output":1,"Action":0}
```

Working on a Sonoff Basic with Tasmota 12.0.x

Any thoughts?